# How to exit the program if exit option is selected?

Tags: c#

Good evening.

Apologies for the noob question, I am new to C# so I'm still getting to grips with a few things. I am trying to write a simple program as shown below, but I'm struggling to get the coding correct for the exit function. How can I write this code to exit to program if the exit option is input, as 'if choice ==4' does not seem to work?

```
// Demonstrate branching and loops.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Fundamentals
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            do
            {

                // Example: Switch.
                Console.WriteLine("Main Menu");
                Console.WriteLine("1 - Play. ");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - Options. ");
                Console.WriteLine("3 - Help.  ");
                Console.WriteLine("4 - Exit.  ");
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Playing the game.");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        // Example: do... while loop.
                        double ans;
                        do
                        {
                            Console.Write("What is: 10 x 10 = ");
                            ans = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        } while (ans != 100);
                        Console.WriteLine("\nCorrect!\n");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Game settings.\n");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Game Help.\n");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Exiting...\n");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
             
                if (choice == "4")
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }

            } while (true);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `choice` is an `int`. `choice == "4"` will always be false, because `"4"` is a `string` and never equal to `4`. Indeed, the code shouldn't even compile, because there's no `==` operator that takes an `int` and a `string` as its two operands. You should be getting a compiler error on that line. Just change it to `choice == 4`.

Comment: For future reference, "doesn't work" isn't a useful problem description. You need to explain _exactly_ what happens, and how that's different from what you want. If any error message is displayed, you need to include the _exact text_ of the error message. If there's an exception, you need to include the full stack trace for the exception. See [mcve] and [ask]. You should also read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) sections of the site.

Comment: This is not a criticism, just an observation. I can't even remember how long I've been writing C#, and I don't think I've ever actually used the "do" construct. You've used it twice on your first day. It always amazes me how many "correct" ways there are to do things even in highly structured languages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would've saved yourself from having this problem by putting your Environment.Exit() call inside the switch statement that is correctly comparing two int's, rather than re-evaluating a condition after evaluating the conditions...

Those that said int is never equal to string are on the money, but if I may suggest an even more correct solution you shouldn't have that if statement at all.

```
 switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Playing the game.");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    // Example: do... while loop.
                    double ans;
                    do
                    {
                        Console.Write("What is: 10 x 10 = ");
                        ans = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    } while (ans != 100);
                    Console.WriteLine("\nCorrect!\n");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Game settings.\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Game Help.\n");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Exiting...\n");
                    Environment.Exit(0);  //// Just exit from here...
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I'm still learning, but the feedback is great and encouraging.

Answer (score 2):

choice is an `int` and you're comparing it to a `string` - so

```
if (choice == 4)
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

for the code you posted- but you could just put the exit code in the case:

```
case 4: 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exiting...\n");
    Environment.Exit(0);
    break;
}
```